# Host Institution - Marie-Curie individual fellowship

Tags: funding, eu, marie-curie

I am planning to apply for a Marie-Curie individual fellowship. Should I be already a Postdoctoral Fellow at a particular University, which will also be the host Institution? In other words, could I assign a host Institution and in case that I receive the fellowship, I can then start working on it?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

For Marie Curie fellowships you **shouldn't** already be employed by the host institution. These fellowships are meant to encourage mobility so you must apply to go to some other place.

> could I assign a host Institution and in case that I receive the fellowship, I can then start working on it?

Yes that's exactly the principle. However be careful: you don't just pick a host institution, the key factor in these fellowships is to have a strong research plan prepared in collaboration with the host institution.